# Can this non-linear boundary-value problem be solved analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, nonlinear-analysis

I am trying to solve
$$
[y^2(x)]''+\frac{x}{2} y'(x) = 0
$$
on $x\in\mathbb{R}$, with the conditions
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} y(x) = a,\qquad
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} y(x) = b.
$$

I am particularly interested in non-negative solutions, $y(x)\geq0$, and the case where $a\neq b$. This means I cannot integrate by parts on the second term, so I'm rather stuck. Searching the usual places (Google, Wolfram alpha) hasn't returned anything interesting.

Comment: I can't promise you this works, but mybe try a power series approach...

Comment: @Meowdog. The problem will be to handle the conditions at $\pm \infty$

Comment: Yes, but maybe start with any initial value first. Then you can adjust it accordingly

Comment: Taking $y=x^2z$, $x=e^t$ then $z'_t=p(z)$ the equation is reduced by one order to an Abel equation of the second kind $zpp'_z+3zp+2z^2+(p+2z)^2+\frac14(p+2z)=0.$